# How to use OSM2pgrouting's mapconfig.xml

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, pgrouting

I would like to find out how to make use of osm2pgrouting's mapconfig.xml to filter out certain types of roads (e.g. roads with private access or highways and highway links). Would prefer to understand how to use them rather than having a answer given to me. Thank you very very much :)